# static functions

Tags: c++, eclipse, optimization, arduino

well i have made an ntp server lib for an arduino program.I want to make the functions i made in the ntp lib static so i can call them from other classes without making objects of that ntp server class.

My problem is that as i make one by one the functions and the variables of the class static (since some functions use some of the class variables) i find myself making a certain function static and then the whole library gives error. The whole library can not understand any variable.I get error that variables can not be resolved also i get error that functions of the NTP class can not bet used since there is not object for them( but it is the functions of the class and there are not implemented in to another class).
i will give you my code.

```
#ifndef NTPLIB_H_
#define NTPLIB_H_

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "IPAddress.h"
#include "EthernetUdp.h"
#include "Ethernet.h"
#include "DayNumber.h"

class NTPlib {

private:


public:
    static EthernetUDP  Udp;
    static DayNumber DN;


    static const int Gmt=2;
    static const unsigned int localPort = 8888;
    static const int NTP_PACKET_SIZE=48;

    static byte  packetBuffer[NTP_PACKET_SIZE ];

    unsigned long secsSince1900;
    unsigned long UnixTime;
    static unsigned long daysPassedInYear;
    static int utchour;
    static int lcthour;
    static int min;
    static int sec;
    static int year;
    static int month;
    static int date;
    static int dayOfWeek;



    NTPlib();
    static NTPlib getTime();
    static bool testNtpServer();
    void startEthernetAndUdp();
    unsigned long  static sendNTPpacket(IPAddress& address);

    virtual ~NTPlib();
};

#endif /* NTPLIB_H_ */
```

this was the header file and here is the .cpp file

```
#include "NTPlib.h"


NTPlib::NTPlib() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

NTPlib NTPlib::getTime(){

    if (testNtpServer()){
        // We've received a packet, read the data from it
        Udp.read((unsigned char*)packetBuffer,NTP_PACKET_SIZE);  // read the packet into the buffer

        //the timestamp starts at byte 40 of the received packet and is four bytes,
        // or two words, long. First, extract the two words:
        unsigned long highWord = word(packetBuffer[40], packetBuffer[41]);
        unsigned long lowWord = word(packetBuffer[42], packetBuffer[43]);

    // combine the four bytes (two words) into a long integer
        // this is NTP time (seconds since Jan 1 1900):
        unsigned long secsSince1900 = highWord << 16 | lowWord;
        Serial.print("Seconds since Jan 1 1900 = " );
        Serial.println(secsSince1900);
        // now convert NTP time into everyday time:
        // Unix time starts on Jan 1 1970. In seconds, that's 2208988800:
        const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL;
        // subtract seventy years:
        unsigned long UnixTime = secsSince1900 - seventyYears;


        sec = UnixTime % 60;
        //calc min
        min = (UnixTime/60)%60;
        //calc hour
        utchour = (UnixTime/3600)%24;
        lcthour = utchour + Gmt;
        //day of the week
        dayOfWeek = (((UnixTime/86400UL) + 3) % 7) + 1;//setting first day Sunday=1

        // print Unix time:
        Serial.print("Unix time = ");
        Serial.println(UnixTime);

        Serial.print("the day is : ");
        Serial.println(dayOfWeek);

        Serial.print("The LTC time is ");
        Serial.println(lcthour);


        unsigned long UnixTimeToDays=UnixTime/86400UL;
        Serial.println(UnixTimeToDays);
        unsigned long calcDaysInYears=0;
        int calcYear=1970;
        while((calcDaysInYears+= (DN.checkLeapYear(calcYear)? 366:365)) <= UnixTimeToDays){
            calcYear++;
        }
        //setting year
        year = calcYear;
        Serial.print("the year is :");
        Serial.println(year);


        //calculating days in this year
        calcDaysInYears -= (DN.checkLeapYear(calcYear)? 366:365);
        daysPassedInYear = UnixTimeToDays - calcDaysInYears;
        Serial.println(daysPassedInYear);

        //set Daynumber one year loop
        DN.Days1YearLoop = daysPassedInYear+1;
        //calculating date and month
        static const uint8_t monthDays[]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

        int calcMonth;
        int monthLength;

        for (calcMonth=0; calcMonth<12;calcMonth++){
            if (DN.checkLeapYear(year)){
                monthLength = (calcMonth==1) ? 29: 28;
            }else{
                monthLength = monthDays[calcMonth];
            }
            if ( daysPassedInYear > monthLength){
                daysPassedInYear -= monthLength;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        month = ++calcMonth;
        date = ++daysPassedInYear;
        Serial.print("Month is : ");
        Serial.print(month);
        Serial.print(" Date is: ");
        Serial.println(date);

        // print the hour, minute and second:
        Serial.print("The UTC time is ");       // UTC is the time at Greenwich Meridian (GMT)
        Serial.print(utchour); // print the hour (86400 equals secs per day)
        Serial.print(':');

        if ( min < 10 ) {
        // In the first 10 minutes of each hour, we'll want a leading '0'
          Serial.print('0');
        }
        Serial.print(min); // print the minute (3600 equals secs per minute)
        Serial.print(':');

        if ( sec < 10 ) {
         // In the first 10 seconds of each minute, we'll want a leading '0'
           Serial.print('0');
        }
        Serial.println(sec); // print the seconds

        return NTPlib();

    }else{
    //error  ntp time from DS1307
        Serial.println("RTC");
        return NTPlib();
    }
}

unsigned long NTPlib::sendNTPpacket(IPAddress& address){

  // set all bytes in the buffer to 0    
  memset(packetBuffer, 0, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);   
  // Initialize values needed to form NTP request    
  // (see URL above for details on the packets)    
  packetBuffer[0] = 0b11100011;   // LI, Version, Mode    
  packetBuffer[1] = 0;     // Stratum, or type of clock    
  packetBuffer[2] = 6;     // Polling Interval    
  packetBuffer[3] = 0xEC;  // Peer Clock Precision    
  // 8 bytes of zero for Root Delay & Root Dispersion    
  packetBuffer[12]  = 49;    
  packetBuffer[13]  = 0x4E;    
  packetBuffer[14]  = 49;    
  packetBuffer[15]  = 52;    
  // all NTP fields have been given values, now
  // you can send a packet requesting a timestamp:    
  Udp.beginPacket(address, 123); //NTP requests are to port 123    
  Udp.write(packetBuffer,NTP_PACKET_SIZE);    
  Udp.endPacket();

}

void NTPlib::startEthernetAndUdp(){

//declaration of the mac address of ethernet shield
    byte mac[]= {0x00,0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDE,0x02};   
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {   
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");   
        // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore: 
        //for(;;)   
        //  ;  
    }

    Udp.begin(localPort);
}

bool NTPlib::testNtpServer(){

    byte serverslist[4][4]={
            193,93,167,241,
            129,215,160,240,
            138,195,130,71,
            132,163,4,101
    } ;
    IPAddress ntpServers(serverslist[0]);
    sendNTPpacket(ntpServers);
    int x=0;
    delay(1000);

    while(!Udp.parsePacket() && x<=3){
            x++;
            IPAddress ntpServers(serverslist[x]);
            Serial.println("ton pairneis");
            sendNTPpacket(ntpServers);
            delay(1000);
        }

    if (x<=3){
        Serial.print("leitoyrgei o server ");
        Serial.println(++x);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


NTPlib::~NTPlib() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

well at first i made gettime function static and ofcourse all the related variables.After that i had to make testNTPServer function static and from i had only 1 error. The error was

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   cannot call member function 'long unsigned int NTPlib::sendNTPpacket(IPAddress&)' without object    NTPlib.cpp  /NTP/lib    line 191    C/C++ Problem

This function is a function of the class it shouldn't need object. also when i do this function static all cpp give Undefined Reference to all of the variables of the class.One example is this:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   more undefined references to `NTPlib::packetBuffer' follow  NTPlib.cpp  /NTP/lib    line 149    C/C++ Problem

Any help?

Comment: This is fixable, but you might be better off *not* using a class full of static functions, but rather, placing non-member functions inside a namespace. Similarly for const static data.

Comment: You have to *define* the static data members. So far, as far as i can see, you have only *declared* them.

Comment: i am not sure i can follow you.you mean that i only declare the objects of the daynumber and ethernetudp class? this is because the their constructor has not operators and also that i can not inithialize them at the header file.also i use some functions of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, when you declare static data members inside a class declaration, you also have to provide definitions for those data members in a source file:

Header File:

```
class C
{
    static int MyInt;
};
```

Source File:

```
int C::MyInt = 0;
```

Comment: but why this definition problem appears after i make the last function static and not when i do the gettime static that has the most of the variables.Also inside gettime function the variables get initialization. Also most of the variables get initialized in header file.Some of them should not get values before the gettime function runs.

Comment: Also if i do this "NTPlib::sec = UnixTime % 60;" inside a function i get the same error. And what about the variables that i can not just set to zero or thati initialize them from header.

Comment: like pucketbuffer or the udp.read that it does not understand the udp object that it's constructor has no operants.

Comment: Don't put static member variable definitions in a function, just put them at the top of a source file (after your includes, for example).

Comment: yes thx for that but i want these variables to get values from the functions not to have something as values.I do not like very much to set hour and sec and everything to zero.is this the only way to fix this? and how do i know that this wont give me error when i try to check the values. i mean how this will keep the new values from gettime etc?

Comment: also if i define their values after include there is no reason to declare them in the header file. it does not understand DN object i have to set again "DayNumber DN=DayNumber(); and this goes for all variables also and the constants.

Comment: Sorry but i have set all variables after include to zero and the error is not resolved also i have a problem setting the pucketbuffer[48] to cause i have to make it ={0,0,0,0,0,...};(48 zeros)